# Vaadin with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, converters, vaadin

Hi SO i'm newbie in Vaadin, tries to create form and bind to that POJO object.

```
...Some declaration

Binder<User> binder = new Binder<>(User.class);

@Autowired
public FormUser(UserRepository userRepository, AuthorityRepository authorityRepository){
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.authorityRepository = authorityRepository;

    authorities = new ListSelect<>("Authorities", authorityRepository.findAll());
    authorities.setItemCaptionGenerator(Authority::getAuthority);

    //Set items
    username.setIcon(FontAwesome.USER);
    password.setIcon(FontAwesome.USER_SECRET);
    saveButton.addClickListener(e -> {
        userRepository.save(user);
    });

    setSpacing(true);
    addComponents(username, password, authorities, saveButton);
    binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
}
```

When try to access view that contains **FormUser** get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property type 'java.util.Collection' doesn't match the field type 'java.util.Set< dev.gva.model.Authority >'. Binding should be configured manually using converter.

**Authority** :

```
public class Authority{
   private Long id;
   private String authority;

   getter/setters..
}
```

**User**:

```
public class User{
   private Long id;
   private Collection<Authority> authorities;

   other fields, getters/setters...
}
```

How to write this converter? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `authorities.setConverter(new Converter<Set<Authority>, Collection<Authority>>(){/*...*/})`?

Comment: @A.Meier I'll try soon, thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

Instead adding boilerplate code for conversions you should use **Set** or **List** for your `authorities`-attribute within the `User`-class. An advantage of that would be also that no duplicates are allowed in `authorities`. The difference between **Set** and **List** is that **List** is ordered and could be accessed by an index. You decide what you need, but **Set** might be enough.